# Can't get network operator string on tablet

Tags: android, tablet, nexus-7

Currently I was working on an app and I wanted to add a function to keep track of the type of telco/service provider they are on for analytic purpose.
But i found out that if the user using on a tablet with mobile internet (eg. nexus 7 3g), i won't be able to get the name for service provider. I've tried  `getSimOperator()` and `getNetworkOperatorName()` and both returning null values. Is there any way possible to get the service provider name or is not possible for device that can't make phone call ?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation of [getnetwordOperatorName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName%28%29) it says:

> Returns the alphabetic name of current registered operator.
>
> **Availability:** Only when user is registered to a network. Result may be **unreliable** on CDMA networks (use getPhoneType() to determine if on a CDMA network).

As you see that result may be unreliable for CDMA networks. So check if you are using CDMA. That's my one cents.

Comment: it appears that is was my own mistake. I've accidentally turned on the airplane mode so it can get any values. Now i switch back to normal mode and it works. Btw thanks for your tips on the checking part too, it guided me to the right path although is not CDMA related.